# Inhomogeneous system of differential equations where $\det A(t)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

We have been given an inhomogeneous system 
$$y'=\begin{bmatrix}5 & -3 & 2 \\ 15 & -9 & 6 \\ 10 & -6 & 4\end{bmatrix}y+\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\x\end{pmatrix}, y(0) = (1,1,0)$$
to solve.

What I have learned is to eliminate until I have only one equation, which I can solve. I don't think I can eliminate though, the matrix $A$ has only rank 1. This also means that I can't use eigenvectors as far as I know.

How can I bring the system into an easily solvable form? Can I **use** the fact that $A$ is of rank 1 somehow?

Comment: Or simply $y'_2-3y'_1=0$ and $y'_3-2y'_1=x$ with $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$

Comment: Have you learned the variation of parameters method yet? The complementary solution to this equation is fairly simple and the necessary calculations to apply that method aren’t too onerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'=\begin{bmatrix}5 & -3 & 2 \\ 15 & -9 & 6 \\ 10 & -6 & 4\end{bmatrix}y+\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\x\end{pmatrix}, y(0) = (1,1,0)$$
I substitued $y=(r,s,t)$:
$$\pmatrix {r \\ s \\ t}'=\pmatrix{5r  -3s + 2t \\ 3r' \\ 2r'+x }$$
Integrate the last two lines:
$$\pmatrix {r' \\ s \\ t}=\pmatrix{5r  -3s + 2t \\ 3r +c_2\\ 2r+\frac 12 x^2+c_3 }$$
$$\pmatrix {r' \\ s \\ t}=\pmatrix{x^2+2c_3-3c_2 \\ 3r +c_2\\ 2r+\frac 12 x^2+c_3 }$$
Integrating first line:
$$\pmatrix {r \\ s \\ t}=\pmatrix{\frac 1 3 x^3+x(2c_3-3c_2)+c_1 \\ 3r +c_2\\ 2r+\frac 12 x^2+c_3 }$$
$$y(x)=\pmatrix{\frac 1 3 x^3+x(2c_3-3c_2)+c_1 \\  x^3+3x(2c_3-3c_2)+3c_1 +c_2\\ \frac 2 3 x^3+2x(2c_3-3c_2)+2c_1+\frac 12 x^2+c_3 }$$
You have to apply the initial conditions and find the three constants. Note that the method of eigenvectors and eigenvalues works fine too. You have  $\lambda=0$ as eigenvalue with multiplicity $3$.
$$(c_1,c_2,c_3)=(1,-2,0)$$
$$ \implies y(x)=\pmatrix{\frac 1 3 x^3+6x+1 \\  x^3+18x+1\\ \frac 2 3 x^3+\frac 12 x^2 +12x+2}$$

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it is well written. How can we use the eigenvector method if there isn't a basis of eigenvectors? Wouldn't we need 3 distinct eigenvectors? (I'm not familiar with the method this is just what I've seen so far)

Comment: Thank you Ruben. There are generalized eigenvectors for repeated eignevalues. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

As we can verify

$$
y'_2=y'_1+y'_3-x
$$

or

$$
y_2=y_1+y_3-\frac 12 x^2+C
$$

so substituting $y_2$ into the DEs

$$
y'_1=g_1(y_1,y_2,y_3)\\
y'_3=g_3(y_1,y_2,y_3)+x
$$

we have the reduced system

$$
\cases{y'_1=g_1(y_1,y_1+y_3-\frac 12 x^2+C,y_3)\\
y'_3=g_3(y_1,y_1+y_3-\frac 12 x^2+C,y_3)+x
}
$$